# Date is not sorted in reporting services consecutively and correctly

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, datetime

I am trying to generate a report using the SSRS,but the date is not being sorted

as I want when running the query.

It is being shown as follow (consecutive months are mixed):

28/05/2014

28/06/2014

29/05/2014

29/06/2014

What I need is to have it as follow (all consecutive days in the same month) :

28/05/2014

29/05/2014

28/06/2014

29/06/2014

Note that I am using this expression to convert the date :

**convert(nvarchar(50),dbo.mytable.manufacturyDate,103)**

Comment: Double check to see if the format for the field is date.

Comment: You've converted to a string, and it's sorting as a string. Why do you want a regional, ambiguous format? What is the query that feeds this report?

Comment: it is a datetime in the table, that's why I convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My default value was a **datetime** and converting it to text was the problem when

sorting.So I removed the convert in my expression and make sure in the

**manufacturyDate** text properties that it is a *dd/MM/yyyy*

[image]

Comment: That is the right way to solve your problem. So please accept this answer so that the system and people that foind your question know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Scorpion99's solution usually works, but in my particular case it wasn't because the date field was coming from the database as a `VARCHAR2` and not a `DATE`. One solution is to convert to a `DATE` in the query, but you can also convert the field to a date in the Interactive Sorting expression:

**Context Click -> Textbox Properties -> Interactive Sorting -> Sort by:**

Then enter an expression like this:

`=CDate(Fields!DateField.Value)`

This method does not change the visual format of the field, it simply sorts the field as a date instead of a string.